# PapaParse : Arrays undefined after reading - React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, csv, papaparse

I am reading in a CSV file from a URL path using Papa.parse. The only issue is that once this is read in, I can not calculate the length and therefore iterate through the array to only access certain information in order to calculate min/max of certain columns.

This throws the error:
`Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')`
when trying to calculate the length of the array parsed.
Is there any reason to why Papa.parse does this? I have used it with Promise functions to merge data using Mapbox JS, however I have had issues with accessing the data within the parsed object.

I know Papa is an asynchronous library, I have attempted to put this into a function with no avail. I wish to use these min/max_val values later on for data-driven styling so I would like it to be accessible and not undefined after calculation.

The code used is as follows:

```
let access_base;
let t;
let csv_data;

const csvData = Papa.parse(url, {
    skipEmptyLines: true,
    dynamicTyping: true,
    download: true,
    complete: function (input) {
    access_base = input.data;
    }
});

t = access_base.length;

for (var i=1; i<t; i++) {
    csv_data.push(access_base[i][3])
};

var min_val = Math.min(csv_data);
var max_val = Math.max(csv_data);
```

I have also attempted:

```
const csvData = Papa.parse(url, {
    skipEmptyLines: true,
    dynamicTyping: true,
    download: true,
    complete: function (input) {
        getMinMax(input.data);
    }
});

 function getMinMax(access_base) {
   var t = access_base.length;
   let csv_data;
   for (var i=1; i<t; i++) {
        csv_data.push(access_base[i][3])
   };
   var min_val = Math.min(csv_data);
   var max_val = Math.max(csv_data);
}
```

Any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: In `getMinMax`, you declare a local `csv_data` variable. Remove this variable and set the `csv_data = []` instead. You already have a global `csv_data`.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I do not have a global ```csv_data``` variable, as it says ```csv_data``` is undefined when removing this line and replacing it with ```csv_data = []```.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no issue with the getMinMax function version of your code. As you state it is a asynchronous library, therefore all of it has been done within the Papa.parse function and it can be parsed to other functions. Check that your URL is displaying the data correctly. You can also parse it to a Promise and debug it to see that it is reading your CSV successful:

```
    function papaPromise(url) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
            Papa.parse(url, {
                download: true,
                header: true,
                skipEmptyLines: true,
                complete: resolve,
                dynamicTyping: true,
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: There is no issue with the parser taking in the data from the URL, through debugging I can see the data in a global variable called access_base. Maybe there is a issue with the fact it is a global variable? I know JavaScript does not like global variables that much, however I have limited experience in React.